# I Don't Know why it's not work create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

PS E:\shareme\shareme_frontend>  npx create-react-app@next --scripts-version=@next --template=cra-template@next ./

You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0-next.60+6a3315b7, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Comment: I'm not sure you are following the instructions since you're adding strange arguments to the command? `npx create-react-app your-app` or `npx create-react-app your-app --template typescript`

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First open a new terminal window. Try doing

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

Then execute any one of the following:-

```
npx create-react-app@latest your-app-name --use-npm
npx create-react-app@latest your-app-name
```